# XAMPP MYSQL refuse to start

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm using XAMPP version 3.2.4 and it was working normally for a while, but suddenly today when trying to start MYSQL it refuse to start and logs file display:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-08-03 12:08:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-08-03 12:08:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-08-03 12:08:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-08-03 12:08:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-08-03 12:08:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-08-03 12:08:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-08-03 12:08:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-08-03 12:08:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-08-03 12:08:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-08-03 12:08:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-08-03 12:08:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-08-03 12:08:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-08-03 12:08:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 2055444129; transaction id 138579
2020-08-03 12:08:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-08-03 12:08:26 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-08-03 12:08:26 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

and as you see all are notes and no error but when I check to windows event viewer I found this error:

> Failed to create a new master info file (file
> 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\master-2020@002d08@002d03@0020@00201@003a01@003a27@002016@0020@005bwarning@005d@0020aborted@0020connection@002016@0020to@0020db@003a@0020@0027ts_ninja@0027@0020user@003a@0020@0027root@0027@0020host@003a@0020@0027localhost@0027@0020@0028got@0020an@0020error@0020reading@0020communication@0020packets@0029@000d.info',
> errno 2)

, I tried to change `max_allowed_packet=128M` from `1M` but still the same, any help will be appreciated (note that Apache successfully start)

Comment: Did you also check the Windows Event Viewer for messages/errors from mariaDB?

Comment: i fount this error :`Failed to create a new master info file (file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\master-2020@002d08@002d03@0020@00201@003a01@003a27@002016@0020@005bwarning@005d@0020aborted@0020connection@002016@0020to@0020db@003a@0020@0027ts_ninja@0027@0020user@003a@0020@0027root@0027@0020host@003a@0020@0027localhost@0027@0020@0028got@0020an@0020error@0020reading@0020communication@0020packets@0029@000d.info', errno 2)`

Comment: Is that why you changed the config for `max_allowed_packet`

Comment: Yes, while I'm searching I found forum recommend to increase `max_allowed_pocket` to solve this issue